# what is the best way to communicate among multiple raspberry pi boards?

Tags: wireless-communication, circuit-design, networking

so i was planning to make a project were a system of computers( in my case raspberry pi's) need to communicate to do a certain job. And i am having a trouble choosing a way of communications. so i would like it if any one has some thing to offer.

here are my needs, and thoughts,

**Needs**

- i want a data to be transferred between multiple raspberry pi boards. The data includes videos frame by frame, and some sensor data.
- i want it to use the smallest amount of time possible for transferring data. since the boards are going to be attached on moving objects i need to have a fast communication in order for each of them to make decision depending on the others data.
- i want each board not to be dependent on the other during network fails

**Thoughts**

- Use a computer as server or the man in the middle to handle data transfers and also do some computations.
- use WiFi or Bluetooth modules to create connections.

those are my thoughts and needs so, suggest me any design principles you now, their advantages, and disadvantages.

Comment: What type of data are you planing of transferring? Is this video, or period data from sensors.

Comment: Your question is too broad, and lacks specifics.  And throwing the phrase "most or least of (anything) possible" is a dangerous thing to do among engineers -- usually all you learn is that you lacked knowledge as to the limits that humanity has already reached.  You mean "smallest amount I'm willing to pay for", and you haven't put any bounds on how much $$$ you have or at what point the time is small enough.

Comment: @Mahendra Gunawardena, most of it is video, frame by frame, but there are also some sensor datas

Comment: You pretty much have to use wifi. Since your data is video this Eliminates Bluetooth. Please update the question with this new information.

Comment: wouldn't using a computer as the central communication mechanism be better.

Comment: Use ethernet cables, then use power over ethernet in your system. This eliminates need of power cables, just wiring the ethernet.

Comment: Base on the information provided you almost need a central computer/Server. Take a look at Greengrass from Amazon.